# Vue composition API: Templates not filled from object created by Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, vue-component, vue-composition-api

If your `setup()` function returns a plain object, for example `{ spec: { name: 'BLAH' }`, Vue dutifully applies it to your template as expected. No rocket science there.

However, if your `setup()` function returns an object created by `Object.defineProperty({}, 'spec', { value: { name: 'BLAH' }})`, Vue ignores `spec` completely. (The specific error message is `Property or method "spec" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`).

Why is this, and how does one change the `Object.defineProperty` call to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Add `enumerable: true` to the options. Like so:

```
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'spec', {
        value: { name: 'BLAH' },
        enumerable: true,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create properties with `Object.defineProperty` and don't specify values in the property descriptor, they generally default to `false`.  In other words, it's essentially the same as:

```js
{
  value: {
     name: 'BLAH',
  },
  enumerable: false,
  writable: false,
  configurable: false
}
```

But the property must be `enumerable: true` for reactivity, presumably because the proxy can't work with it properly otherwise.  So this works:

```js
Object.defineProperty({}, 'spec', { value: { name: 'BLAH' }, enumerable: true })
```